# Binary tree of doubles/comparison of doubles C++

Tags: c++, comparison, double, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement a binary tree with doubles, but I believe my doubles comparison is not correct.  When I feed it ints it works properly; however, if I insert doubles with many trailing decimal places, I get a segfault.

Here's what my insertion function looks like:

```
int BinaryTree::insert_node(double val, char *str){;
  return insert_node_helper(this->root, val, str); 
}


int BinaryTree::insert_node_helper(TreeNode *&node, double val, char *str){

  if(node == NULL){
    node = new TreeNode;
    node->val = val;
    node->str = strdup(str);
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return 0;
  }else if(val > node->val){ 
    return insert_node_helper(node->right, val, str);
  }else{
    return insert_node_helper(node->left, val, str);
  }

  return 1;
}
```

TreeNode definition:

```
struct TreeNode {
   double val;
   char *str;
   TreeNode *left;
   TreeNode *right;
};
```

Calling code:

```
void HashTable::chi_squared(){

  int numTokens = numBigrams + 1;
  BinaryTree topBigrams;
  int treeInsertions = 0;

  //indices for confusion matrix
  int o11, o12, o21, o22 = 0;
  int w1, w2, notW1, notW2 = 0;
  double e11, e12, e21, e22 = 0;
  double x2 = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if(table[i] != NULL){
      TokenList *temp = table[i]->tl;
      while(temp != NULL){

    Entry *temp2 = search(temp->str);
    if(temp2 == NULL){
      printf("string (  %s  ) \n", temp->str);
      temp = temp->next;
      continue;
    }

    o11 = temp->occurrences;  //total occurrences of word1 followed by word2
    o21 = table[i]->occurrences - temp->occurrences;  //total occurrences of word1 not followed by word2
    o12 = search(temp->str)->occurrences - temp->occurrences;  //total occurrences of not word1 followed by word2
    o22 = numTokens - o11 - o12 - o21;   //total occurrences of not word1 followed by not word2

    w1 = table[i]->occurrences;
    w2 = search(temp->str)->occurrences;
    notW1 = numTokens - w1;
    notW2 = numTokens - w2;

    e11 = (w1 / (double)numTokens) * (w2 / (double)numTokens) * numTokens;
    e12 = (notW1 / (double)numTokens) * (w2 / (double)numTokens) * numTokens;
    e21 = (w1 / (double)numTokens) * (notW2 / (double)numTokens) * numTokens;
    e22 = (notW1 / (double)numTokens) * (notW2 / (double)numTokens) * numTokens;

    x2 = (pow((o11 - e11), 2) / (double)e11) + 
      (pow((o12 - e12), 2) / (double)e12) +
      (pow((o21 - e21), 2) / (double)e21) +
      (pow((o22 - e22), 2) / (double)e22);

    x2 /= 100;

    if(x2 >= 50){
      if(treeInsertions < 100){
        topBigrams.insert_node(x2, strcat(strcat(temp->str, "  "), table[i]->str));
        treeInsertions++;
      }else if(x2 > topBigrams.find_min()->val){
         topBigrams.replace_min(x2, strcat(strcat(temp->str, "  "), table[i]->str));

    }

    temp = temp->next;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

x2 normally looks something like: 50.91747014595311071616
However if it's 50 or any other whole number, insert works just fine.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Can we see the calling code, the class definition of TreeNode and the definitions of the insert_node_helper function, please?

Comment: Is this okay? Or should I post more?

Comment: Never, **EVER** use approximate comparison for sorting. It is not transitive. `(val < node->val)` and `(val > node->val)` should work.

Comment: `abs` returns int, you should use `fabs`. And you shouldn't use `char *` with manual memory management - use `std::string`.

Comment: Can we see where you define temp and table, those strcat's look suspicious.

Comment: per @n.m.'s suggestion, I have removed the approximate comparison

Comment: Let me be more specific, `strcat` does not allocate new space. So how do you know `temp->str` is large enough to hold the results of the `strcat`?

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for the suggestion!  It could overflow, but I don't think that's the problem here because I only ever pass in char buffers of size 1024, but I know that I don't have any strings nearly that size in the input. (And I've already read in all the data with a different, but similar algorithm using ints).